# The difference between the two lists with sublists by the first element in each sublist

Tags: python

I have a problem in python.
I need to get differences between the two lists with sublists, but I need only comparing first element of each sublists.

Example:

Input:

```
x=[[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]]

y=[[1,8],[5,1]]
```

Output:

```
dif_l=[[5,1]]
```

Summarizing the problem, I have to subtract the x list from the y list (dif_l=y-x), but only check first element from each sublists.

Comment: Does your logic means that if for any sublist in `y` the first item happens to be also the first item of some sub-list in `x` then remove those sub-lists from `y`?

Comment: @daamiansz how you calculated this output?

Comment: Can you please explain better what the logic is behind this? It is not that clear to me.

Comment: What if `y=[[2,8],[1,5]]`

Answer (score 1):

Can use list comprehension:

```
    x=[[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]]

    y=[[1,8],[5,1]]

    diff_l = [l for l in y if l[0] not in [k[0] for k in x]]
    print(diff_l)
```

Comment: Thank you, Your solution is OK, but i looking for something faster.

Answer (score 1):

Use dicts as an intermediate step with the first values as keys. Return only those keys not found in the other dict.

A solution can look like this.

```
x=[[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]]

y=[[1,8],[5,1]]

def custom_sublist_subtract(left, right):
    ''' y - x should be passed as (y, x)
    '''
    dict_left = {item[0]: item for item in left}
    dict_right = {item[0]: item for item in right}
    result = [v for k, v in dict_left.items() if k not in dict_right]
    return result

custom_sublist_subtract(y, x)
#Output:
[[5, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your code is correct and very fast, that's what I needed